# Mapreduce: NLineInputFormat throwing Error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written Custom Recordreader for our mapper to receive 3 records ( 3 lines ) from the source file at a time instead on 1 line as provided by default by the TextInputFormat. Below are the sample code snippets.

**Extending TextInputFormat:**

```
public class NLinesInputFormat extends TextInputFormat{
    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>; createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
        return new NLinesRecordReader();
    }
}
```

**Custom RecordReader class**

```
public class NLinesRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>{
    private final int NLINESTOPROCESS = 3;
    private LineReader in;
    private LongWritable key;
    private Text value = new Text();
    private long start =0;
    private long end =0;
```

modified driver to use the new input format by added following line of code

```
job.setInputFormatClass(NLinesInputFormat.class);
```

But the above line throwing the below Error

```
The method setInputFormatClass(Class<? extends InputFormat>) in the type Job is not applicable for   the arguments (Class<NLinesInputFormat>)
```

I am not sure what causing this Error. I am not mixing any old and the new API. I am using using new API only. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write Custom NLineInpuFormat, its already available.

try this,

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setInt(
            "mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 3);
    Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
    job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
```